# Is there any special category for external files in project file of Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, projects-and-solutions

I'd like to keep in my project some *external* files, let's say .txt ones.
Is there any special category for external files in project file (.pro) of Qt Creator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt Creator, at least, uses an OTHER_FILES variable for .txt files and anything similar:

```
OTHER_FILES += test.txt
```

Adds "test.txt" to the "Project Files" pane in Qt Creator.

---

If you want to group your files a bit, what you can try is adding a separate .pri file such as "External.pri", including your external files from there, and then including the .pri file in your .pro:

**Project.pro**

```
HEADERS += someclass.h
SOURCES += main.cpp someclass.cpp
...
include(External.pri)
```

**External.pri**

```
OTHER_FILES += license.txt todo.txt
```

Which has the effect of creating a folder of sorts (called "External") in Qt Creator. If you have a bunch of external files it'll help keep things organized.

Comment: Is OTHER_FILES copying the external files to the directory of the published project? Because it is not happening in my case...

Comment: @faif, you should either specify relative path from `.pro` location, of full path, AFAIK. QtCreator won't copy anything.